# How detect first index of each line inside a string with multiple lines?

Tags: swift, string, newline

I have a `string` that includes multiple lines and each line seperated with different seperator like `\r\n` or `\n` or etc. So I used `CharacterSet.newlines` to detect lines. But I also want first index of each sentence. How can I achieve this?

I use below code for seperating lines:

```
for (i, mySentence) in sampleString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).enumerated() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose I would “manually” search the newline characters, so that
both the current substring and its position are available:

```
let sampleString = "aaa\naaa\r\nbbb\rccc"

var lines = [String]()
var positions = [String.Index]()

var pos = sampleString.startIndex // Current position
while let r = sampleString[pos...].rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines) {
    if pos != r.lowerBound {
        lines.append(String(sampleString[pos..<r.lowerBound]))
        positions.append(pos)
    }
    pos = r.upperBound // Continue _after_ the newline character
}
// The final component:
if pos != sampleString.endIndex {
    lines.append(String(sampleString[pos...]))
    positions.append(pos)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The index is the `lowerBound` of the range of `mySentence` in `sampleString`. The variable `startIndex` is used as an offset to skip already processed lines.

```
let sampleString = "aaa\naaa\n\rbbb\rccc"

var startIndex = sampleString.startIndex
let firstIndexes = sampleString.components(separatedBy: .newlines).compactMap { line -> String.Index? in
    guard let range = sampleString[startIndex...].range(of: line) else { return nil }
    startIndex = range.upperBound
    return range.lowerBound
}

print(firstIndexes)
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there exists repetitive lines inside `sampleString`. So with your proposed way I must store each range inside a dictionary and in each loop check that it is passed or not inside loop. I look for a simpler way

Comment: It's perfect that I can get an array of first indexes that includes first index of each line.

Comment: I updated the answer to consider repetitive lines and to get an array of (first) indexes. The `i` loop index is actually not used.

Comment: Try this with `"aaa\naaa\r\nbbb\rccc"` – it finds the same index for the first two lines, and then crashes.

Comment: I also see the problem that @Martin mentioned.

Comment: (I hope) the issue is fixed now.

Comment: The problem fixed now. I did up voting answers of you and @Martin